# Specifying constant value in the gridview hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with a HyperLinkField column where the DataNavigateUrlFormatString is as following:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DetailedPage.aspx?OrderNo={0}"
```

I would like to add to the above DataNavigateUrlFormatstring another value – constant - so that the called page (DetailedPage can get both the value of OrderNo (passed dynamically) and the same value for all rows.

For example, the url would be something like:
DetailedPage.aspx?OrderNo=100&filename=’myfilename.doc’

Note, again that the name ‘myfilename.doc’ is the same for all rows but will be known in the OnLoad of the page.  Ideally I would like the second value (e.g. myfilename.doc) to be hidden from the URL
but if this is not possible, it will still work.

How can I do it?

Comment: If it's going to be the same doc for every record, why not just put the doc in a folder and simply access it from there in the Detailed page?

Comment: @IrishChieftain There could be more than one page with GridView and each one will have a different file name. And therefore there will be a number of DetailedPages, each one should get a unique file name. So I can't store it in the folder.  Thank you.

Comment: If there's paging with the GridView with different doc for each of these GridView pages then you will have to code for this. Not sure what you mean by "number of" DetailedPages?

Comment: @IrishChieftain  What I meant is that at any given time there could be more than one page with gridview. Each page will create a number of detailed pages (if user keeps clicking on different rows of the gridview). So I have to make sure that each detailed page does not rely on session variable, neither on the file stored on drive. It has to be passed to each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TemplateField` with a `HyperLink` control inside and then in the `RowDataBound` event in code-behind, just set the `NavigateUrl` property to the value, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server"   
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        ...Other columns here...
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTempalte>
                <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Details" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Only interact with the data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Find the hyperlink control by ID
        var theHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;

        // Verify we found the hyperlink before we try to use it
        if(theHyperLink != null)
        {
            // Set the NavigateUrl value here
            theHyperLink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("DetailedPage.aspx?OrderNo={0}&filename='{1}'", theOrderNumber.ToString(), theFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `theOrderNumber` and `theFileName` would be values determined upon load of the page from the database, for example.

Comment: Karl, Thank you. I will Google for an example of how to do it. From the "look" of it, it should work.

Comment: In the RowDataBound method I can iterate through the rows. But how do I determine which row is the Hyperlink row?
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
         // put code here to set the Hyperlink string
       }
(Sorry don't know how to format code in the comment)

Comment: @Hidalgo - sorry, I was updating the answer with an example. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been hitting my head against the wall for 2 hours with this problem you saying that 2 minutes was too long .. LOL.

Comment: @Hidalgo - Let me know if it does not work, because I wrote it off the top of my head, so let me know and I will help you through it if I can. :-)

Comment: Karl, I am pretty sure it will work (and I will click on the solution once I am done). I am just working on how to get the OrderNumber inside the GridView1_RowDataBound method. 
Again, thank you.

Comment: @Hidalgo - two possibilities for storing the order number is a hidden field control (`<asp:HiddenField>`) or `Session` cache, either of which gets loaded the first time the page is loaded and stored for subsequent post backs. This way the value is only looked up once from the database or wherever you are getting it from (query string maybe). Just a thought.

Comment: @Hidalgo - great, glad it worked out. Feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-) Good luck to you.